# Using Swift to display Array in MainStoryboard Table View?

Tags: arrays, uitableview, swift, tableview

I'm halfway capable of creating an array using the Swift language. But then being able to map this array to be displayed in the Main.storyboard on iOS is where I'm drawing a blank. I comprehend that there can be `TableViewController`s and `TableView`s and `TableViewCell`s, yet somehow I simply cannot make the step from

```
 myArray ["Viktor Schauberger", "Nikola Tesla", "Wilhelm Reich", "John Bedini", "Walter Russell", "Ed Leedskalnin", "R. Buckminster Fuller", "John Keely", "Nathan Stubblefield", "Ismael Aviso", "Hector Perez Torres", "Thomas Henry Moray"]
```

to being able to display it in the iOS Simulator and then work from displaying an array of things to making them tappable. But for now, I'd just be content in figuring out how to use Swift 1.2 to display this Array visually in the `TableView` / `TableViewController` - whichever applies.

Comment: I don't think you're having a Swift problem as much as a UIKit problem.  I suggest reading the details about how `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols work.

Answer (score 1):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as MyCell
    // no "if" - the cell is guaranteed to exist
    // ... do stuff to the cell here ...
    cell.textLabel.text = self.Myarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row;
    // ...
    return cell
}
```

try this one :)

or goto this link below this might help you https://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/

for loading prototype cell
[prototype cell](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/prototype-cells-tableview-tutorial-ios8-swift)

Comment: Sarath, where should I place this bit of code, please? :)

Comment: hi, I tried to add myArray and your information into it, and got a "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ;"  on     cell.textLabel.text = self.Myarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row;     and overall just got terribly confused. Also, says here "Result and parameters of 'tableview(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)' have different optionality than expected by protocol UITableViewDataSource. Also "Use of undeclared type 'MyCell'.. and so on.

Comment: dude the "MyCell" is the name of the Custom Cell I have created in my project. if you are loading any Custome cell or something you can use that name instead of Mycell

Comment: if you are using prototype cell. i thing the noramal cell for row at index path is sufficient

Comment: tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!